# .NET Core 2.0 RSA PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography, .net-core, rsa

I am trying to use this code to generate a public and private key, I am using .NET Core 2 on Windows 10

So far I had no success in running this code, it compiles just fine but when I get to the rsa.ToXmlString line it drops with a PlatformNotSupportedException and as I read in another answer on stack overflow the solution was using `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` and they showed the almost exact code that I use here down below.

```
        using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            rsa.KeySize = 1024;

            privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
            publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        }
```

Error:
[image]

As seen here it does show up in their API browser, so it has to be supported, right?
[image]

Does anyone have any similar problems? Or does anyone have a fix for this?
I have to use .NET Core so don't suggest using .NET 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's finally been implemented in .NET Core 3.0: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/37593

Answer (score 14):

.Net Core don't have the `toXmlString()` and `fromXmlString` method. but you can use an [extension](https://gist.github.com/Jargon64/5b172c452827e15b21882f1d76a94be4/)

Workarounds:
[#874](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874),
[#23686](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23686)

### Update:

Added `ToXmlString` and `FromXmlString` implementations to `RSA` and `DSA` in .NET Core 3.0

[RSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netframework-4.8) &
[DSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dsa?view=netcore-3.0) examples.

Comment: As I dig a bit deeper into the workarounds, indeed it seemed to work.
Thank you :3 I did have to rename the methods to lowercase to resolve a conflict and change the class from internal to public. but furthermore it seems to work.