# Extracting Asymmetric key under .Net Core

Tags: c#, encryption-asymmetric

I wish to create an asymmetric key in memory in C# under .NetCore 2.0

As a starting point I tried to run the sample given here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container

For example the code here :

```
    // Create the CspParameters object and set the key container   
    // name used to store the RSA key pair.  
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
    cp.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;

    // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses  
    // the key container MyKeyContainerName.  
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);

    // Display the key information to the console.  
    Console.WriteLine("Key added to container: \n  {0}",     rsa.ToXmlString(true));
```

fails because RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString gives a runtime error of

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
```

The definition of this method 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.Toxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx

states that the output parameter returns the XML string (as well as a boolean input parameter).  I have seen some posts where an alternative local implementation of ToXmlString is used, but this passes both the bool and the string into the method - which sounds as if it is doing something completely different and is not equivalent.

How can I get an XML string of an rsa object under .NetCore ?

Comment: Duplicate of [NET Core 2.0 RSA PlatformNotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415078/net-core-2-0-rsa-platformnotsupportedexception) (also contains suggestions how to create a workaround).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core 2.0 RSA PlatformNotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415078/net-core-2-0-rsa-platformnotsupportedexception)