# RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString and RSA.FromXmlString not supported on .net core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cryptography

I am trying to use RSACryptoServiceProvider and/or RSA for signing my requests, and discovered that neither of these work in .net core 2.x although the MS documentation says so..

I wonder if anyone has encountered this issue before and whether that's the documentation got something wrong or that I missed something.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
var privateKeyValidation = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
privateKeyValidation.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);
```

the above code would fail with: "operation is not supported on this platform" if I run it in .net core 2.x, but will work on .net framework 4.5 and .net core 3.1

I wonder if i am missing some assemblies....

Comment: Instead of creating an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instance, use `RSA.Create`. You may not get the traditional Windows crypto service provider, but you'll get an equivalent implementation

Comment: I did try to use RSA.FromXmlString(), not supported for .net core 2.x either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 2.0 RSA PlatformNotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415078/net-core-2-0-rsa-platformnotsupportedexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, apparently Microsoft didnt check their documentation properly...

on the same page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-3.1

it documented that the class is not supported in .net core but also saying that it does... incorrectly stated and misleading.

the truth is here:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874

and you will just have to either copy someone's extension method online (like this one: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23686) or write your own.....